# How to prevent connection to the server without my client application?

Tags: iphone, security, encryption, client-server

A client asked me to do a back-end server for its iPhone application and want only users who bought the application to be able to call the server.
The problem is that he doesn't want to add a login system to the application, so that it seems to me there is no completely safe way to prevent someone without his application calls the server.
In any case, even if it can not be completely prevented, it would be sufficient to make it difficult to access servers without the application.

What is the best way to achieve this? Again, I do not need to fully protect the connection, there is no transit of sensitive information, I just want to make things a little more complicated for people who want to take advantage of server without paying the application.

The idea that seems most simple is to encrypt the data with a key stored within the client and known to the server, so that the message can be decrypted only decompiling the code and finding the key (of course instead of a key you could put a list of keys, which change every 6/12/24 hours).

Could this be a reasonable solution?

Answer (score 0):

This will never be possible.  Welcome to the nature of the client-server architecture.  You can never trust the client.  Just make sure the functionality you are exposing is safe.

Comment: to be honest I was pretty sure of this... Now the problem is it to make it clear to the customer :)

Comment: @Fabio,  There are very few things worse than someone who signs your paychecks and doesn't understand even the most basics concepts of modern security.

Answer (score 0):

well if its a paid app you could release the app for free with all the functionally locked down until a user does a in app purchase and then you could verify the receipt on your server therefore proving that the device is a iOS Device?

Answer (score 0):

sharing a key between the client and the server seems to be a good way to go. But instead of depending on the stored keys only, try combining them with a Unique identifier, such as [UUID](https://github.com/blackpixel/BPXLUUIDHandler) and send it to server both with the combined key, and the UUID itself.

At that point users UUID will be his identifier (username) and the combined key will be his token (password). And this will be a login-like mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

An SSL connection is not enought to prevent other people from getting the URL for the requests? Or even better using an SSL connection with a basic auth?